# How do you convert a WinDef.POINT to a WinDef.POINT.ByValue?

Tags: java, jna

Say I receive a `WinDef.POINT` using `User32.INSTANCE.GetCursorPos`. How can pass this `WinDef.POINT` to a function that requires a `WinDef.POINT.ByValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WinDef.POINT.ByValue` class includes a [`Pointer` constructor](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.9.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef.POINT.ByValue.html#ByValue-com.sun.jna.Pointer-).

You can retrieve the `Pointer` to the `POINT` structure you received using the `Structure` class method `getPointer()`.

So a type safe way of doing it that I'd probably do:

```java
WinDef.POINT thePoint = new WinDef.POINT();
User32.INSTANCE.GetCursorPos(thePoint);
WinDef.POINT.ByValue thePointByVal = new WinDef.POINT.ByValue(thePoint.getPointer());
passThePointToTheOtherFunction(thePointByVal);
```

Knowing the inner workings of the class, I can see the nested `ByValue` class extends the `POINT` class without changing anything about its fields, so simple typecasting would work here, although may be considered a code smell:

```java
WinDef.POINT thePoint = new WinDef.POINT();
User32.INSTANCE.GetCursorPos(thePoint);
passThePointToTheOtherFunction((WinDef.POINT.ByValue) thePoint);
```

Upcasting would work as well is probably "safer" but since we're still intentionally causing different behavior it's relying on implementation details and may also be a code smell:

```java
WinDef.POINT.ByValue thePoint = new WinDef.POINT.ByValue();
// Explicitly upcast to trigger default ByReference behavior
User32.INSTANCE.GetCursorPos((WinDef.POINT) thePoint);
passThePointToTheOtherFunction(thePoint);
```